# Rewriting URLs with Mod_Rewrite 

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Original Question:

> what could be the mod_rewrite, to rewrite urls with this structure: http://hiwis.net/jobs/Computer/ to something with this structure: http://hiwis.net/Computer/

--

I need some help with the mod_rewrite for my hiwis(dot)net site to rewrite URLs with this structure: hiwis(dot)net/jobs/Computer/ to something with this structure: hiwis(dot)net/Computer/ , thanks.

Comment: Just to make it clear: You want that requests to `/jobs/Computer/` are being redirected to `/Computer/`, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/?jobs/Computer/(.*)$ /Computer/$1 [R]
```

Comment: So that it will work whether it's in a server config file or in a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio for the help but, it seems like I'm missing something? it seems to not work at my end. Maybe I should make it clearer my ulr stucture is www.domain.net/something/keyword and I'd like it to be www.domain.net/keyword

Comment: Are you saying that the word in the beginning could be something other than "jobs"?

Comment: no, it's always Jobs, but I've tried the code, and it doesn't seems to work, and it keeps displaying the same way. Thanks for any further help.

Comment: Wait... is it "jobs" or "Jobs"? Patterns are case sensitive, unless you use the  `NC` flag.